# Estimating the sum of Dirichlet character $\sum_{0 \leq x < q} \chi(F(x))$ where $F(x)$ is a polynomial

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory

Let $q \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\chi$ a Dirichlet character mod $q$. Let $F(x)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients. I was wondering if a bound for the following sum was available or not:
$$
\sum_{0 \leq x < q} \chi(F(x)).
$$

I would appreciate any comments and references. Thank you very much!

PS In fact I am also interested in if a more general sum
$$
\sum_{0 \leq x < q} \chi(F(x)) \overline{\chi(G(x) )}
$$ 
can be bounded or not. Here $G$ is another polynomial with integer coefficients.

PPS For the first sum I am particularly interested in the case when $F(x)$ is not identically a constant modulo $q$.

Comment: Well, there is the trivial bound, $q$. If $F(x)$ is a constant, you can't do better. I think your problem is underspecified.

Comment: A good reference for this is the following paper of Chang: https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.0299

Comment: ... in particular you should look at Weil's Theorem (page 7) and Theorem $3^{\prime\prime}$ (page 16). In particular, the latter should give you a non-trivial estimate for your second sum as $\chi(F(x)) \overline{\chi(G(x))}$ can be rewritten as $\chi(F(x)/G(x))$ for all but a few values of $x$.

Comment: Another great reference is chapter 12 of the textbook of Iwaniec and Kowalski.

Comment: @Siksek Thank you very much for all the references!

Comment: @reuns Could you possibly elaborate more on this? I am not familiar enough with Weil's conjecture to derive the conclusion. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm just saying that if $p$ is prime and $\chi$ is a Dirichlet character modulo $p$ of order $k$ then $\displaystyle\frac{1}{k}\sum_{m=1}^k \chi(x)^m = 1_{x \in \mathbb{F}_p^{* \ k}}$ and $\displaystyle\# \{ (x,y)\in\mathbb{F}_p^*, y^k = F(x)\} = \sum_{m=1}^k \sum_{x\in \mathbb{F}_p^*} \chi(F(x))^m$, so it is related to the Weil's conjectures. See Siksek's link and Iwaniec & Kowalski's book.